# Is it possible to return or await for return of cypress intercept?

Tags: cypress

I would like to get the response of an intercept cypress call while running an e2e test:

```js
const registerUser = async (username, password)=>{
    cy.visit('<user_registration_url');
    
    cy.intercept('/registration').as('registration');
    
    
    cy.get('input#username').type(username);
    cy.get('input#password').type(password);
    cy.get('button#submit').click()
    
    // Expected response:
    //{statusCode: 200, body: {userId: <string>}}
    const result = await cy.wait('@registration');
    const userId = result.response.body.userId;
    return userId

it('should test something with a newly registered user', ()=>{
    const userId = registerUser('foobar', 'password');
    // ... keep testing using the userId which was generated on the backend.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So indeed as @pavelsman mentioned there is no async/await syntax for cypress. In order to make utility functions one can return a chainable as in this example:

```js
const registerUser = (username, password)=>{
    cy.visit('<user_registration_url');
    
    cy.intercept('/registration').as('registration');
    
    
    cy.get('input#username').type(username);
    cy.get('input#password').type(password);
    cy.get('button#submit').click()
    
    // Expected response:
    //{statusCode: 200, body: {userId: <string>}}
    return cy.wait('@registration');


it('should test something with a newly registered user', ()=>{
    registerUser('foobar', 'password').then(result=>{
        const userId = result.response.body.userId;
        // ... keep testing using the userId which was generated on the backend.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work.

Cypress is asynchronous, so the commands won't return any data that you can assign to variables. You can read more on then in Cypress [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Return-Values).

You can get to the response like so:

```js
cy
  .wait('@registration')
  .then(response => {
    // some other code
  });
```

or you can check e.g. a status code like so:

```js
cy
  .wait('@registration')
  .its('response.statusCode')
  .should('eq', 201);
```

You can see many examples on the page for [`cy.intercept` command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept).